# Delete **Contents:** in index of pdf generated with python-spihnx

Tags: pdf, sphinx

I have a project created with `python-sphinx` and I use `latexpdf` to compile the final pdf.

In the final pdf created, in the *index* it is visible a *Contents:* string that I would like to delete.

[image]

The only way I found by now is to compile only the `latex`, open the `.tex` file, look for the string and delete that from there.

Then compile the pdf via latex `make all-pdf`.

Is there a way to specify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `Contents:` is almost certainly in your `index.rst` file. It is (or was, things could have changed since) put there when you use `sphinx-quickstart` to initiate a new project.